# How $\int_{\gamma\times\gamma} F(x,y)dxdy$ and $\int_{\gamma} F(x,x)dx$ are related

Tags: complex-analysis

Let $F(x,y)$ be a function of two complex variables, such that $F:{\mathbb C}\times {\mathbb C}\to {\mathbb C}$ is also a Mercer kernel (i.e. $[F(x_i, x_j)]$ is always a PSD matrix), and $F(x,\cdot)^\ast$ and $F(\cdot,x)$ are holomorphic for any $x$ (with possibly only 1 singular point, 0). Let $\gamma\subseteq {\mathbb C}$ be a boundary of a connected closed region containing 0.

How are $\int_{\gamma\times\gamma} F(x,y)dxdy$ and $\int_{\gamma} F(x,x)dx$ related (which inequalities hold)?

Also, the general question: is there any simple criteria for $\int_{\gamma\times\gamma} F(x,y)dxdy$ to be finite?

Comment: I haven’t found a definition of complex-valued kernels, or whether Mercer’s theorem applies to them.

Comment: To simplify, let $F(x,y) = \sum_i \phi_i(x)\phi_i (y)^\ast$, where $\phi_i$ is holomorphic with a singular point 0.

Comment: So, $F(x,y)$ is a symmetric, positive definite kernel on a set ${\mathbb C}$.

Answer (score 1):

A helpful(?) **Hint:**

The mentioned [Mercer's theorem itself is a generalization of the result that any symmetric positive-semidefinite matrix is the Gramian matrix of a set of vectors.](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mercer%27s_theorem#Generalizations)

For Gramian matrix we can use the **triangle inequality**:

$\langle v_1,v_1 \rangle +\langle v_1,v_2 \rangle +\ldots=\| v_1 +v_2 +\ldots\|^2\leq (\| v_1\| + \|v_2\| +\ldots)^2$

Taking square root and generalizing (!?), I claim that:

$$\int F(x,y)dxdy\leq \int F(x,x)dx$$